# Laravel. Listar productos por nombre

Tags: laravel, controller

Tengo mi código en el Controller:

```
public function results(Request $request, $idCategory = 0)
    {

        $category = $this->frontService->categoryById($idCategory);

        if($category){

            $products = $this->frontService->results($idCategory);
            $subcategories = $this->frontService->subcategories($category->parent_id);

            $params = [
                "category" => $category,
                "parent" => $category->parent,
                "subcategories" => $subcategories,
                "products" => $products["products"],
                "hasMorePages" => $products['pagination']['hasMorePages']
            ];

            return view('front.products.results', $params);
        }else{
            return view('front.404');
        }

    }
```

En la URL aparece
http://www.gemetytec.com/productos/3/tablets

y debería ser:
http://www.gemetytec.com/productos/tablets

Comment: tienes que configurar tu ruta para que reciba los datos por nombre en lugar de id, en el archivo web.php pero no lo recomiendo porque un nombre no es un identificador unico y se puede repetir cosa que no pasa con el id.

Comment: Con la configuración existente no se puede solo cambiando la ruta, ya que me arroja el 404